# how can i make a discord bot send the message the author says discord py

Tags: python, discord

```
@bot.command()  
async def lol(ctx):
    for guild in bot.guilds:  # all servers of the bot
        role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'new role', guild.roles)
        for member in guild.members:
            if role in member.roles:
                await member.send(word)
    word = ""
```

this is it so far

if you are feeling generous can you tell me how to use the role the author says

Comment: "the role the author says"  what author? sorry I don't understand your question. What are you talking about? The question doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the bot to send a message, given by the person who invoked the command, to all people with a certain role? If so, here's the code for that:

```py
@bot.command()  
async def lol(ctx, *, msg):
    for guild in bot.guilds:  # all servers of the bot
        role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'new role', guild.roles)
        for member in guild.members:
            if role in member.roles:
                await member.send(msg)
```

Comment: This would work like `/lol hi how are you` and it sends a message saying "hi how are you" to all the members with that role